# Insert into SQLite3 into "middle" of table

Tags: sqlite, sorting

I just want to clarify: if you insert a row to a table in sqlite, it appends it to the table, but -- as I learned -- the table is unordered, so there is really not true way to insert a row into the middle of an "ordered table," right?

Is there even a way to make an ordered table without first created a table and then using `'...ORDER BY name/id/etc'` (i.e. when you insert something it puts itself in the right place)?

Comment: To ask another question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: At the top right: [[Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)]

Comment: Haha. I was just kidding. Thanks, though. :P

Answer (score 0):

SQLite tables are actually stored in [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) order, but this is unlikely to help you because it is unlikely that there is a gap where you want it.

Furthermore, the order in which rows are stored does not matter because there is no guarantee that this is the order in which they are returned.
When you want to SELECT rows in a specific order, you *must* use ORDER BY.

If your query is too slow, an index on the sorting column might help.